# How can I ignore default value on SQL insert statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-ce

I've already set **default** value for some of my columns.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TEST]
(
    [id] [INT] NULL,
    [fname] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [lname] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [default1] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [default2] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [default3] [VARCHAR](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TEST] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_TEST_job] DEFAULT ('test1') FOR [default1]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TEST] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_TEST_default2] DEFAULT ('test2') FOR [default2]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TEST] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_TEST_default3] DEFAULT ('test3') FOR [default3]
```

Now I'm going to set all columns with default values to null in my `INSERT` statement sometimes.

I know that if I provide values for the columns in the `INSERT`, their defaults will be ignored. But I'm looking for a way to set default values off on some inserts. 
I know that it might be impossible, but I want to learn it's way (if there is.

Comment: Please post an example database schema, the SQL you tried and the results you got. Also post the results you want.

Comment: If you want to use the default - **omit** the columns; if you want to skip the defaults - **provide a value** for the column - that's all there is, just use these techniques. There's no *turning OFF defaults* for certain `INSERT` operations....

Comment: Absolutely right, but I will keep my searches on to find a way to do it. I think it would have a way.

Comment: To use the default value, either omit the column or specify the keyword `default` for the value. The specified value will be used in other cases.

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand what you're trying to ask here....

If you **provide** a value for a column - even if it's `NULL`, in your `INSERT` statement, then SQL Server will use **that provided value** and skip any default value defined on the column.

So by just providing `NULL`, you're basically doing what your title asks: ignore the default value of the column.... the default value of a column is **only used** if you **omit** that column entirely from your `INSERT` statement....